# Magento2: Remove Category path from product URL is not working

Tags: magento2, product, url-rewrite, product-urls

I have a Magento2 store. I don't want to add the category path into products URLs for that I set “Use Categories Path for Product URLs” as "NO" in magento2 Admin, but It still add the category path to the product URL.

What I already tried.

1. set “Use Categories Path for Product URLs” as "NO"
2. Did Reindex
3. Next I truncate tables **url_rewrite** and **catalog_url_rewrite_product_category**
4. Did reindex
5. Regenerate products URL

But No results.

Answer (score 1):

You must follow in your admin, `Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> Use Categories Path for Product URLs`, you must change to **No**, and you have to make sure that in the **Website** and **Store View** is **No**.

After that, you must reindex and refresh the cache.

Comment: I have already done this. But nothing changed.

Comment: You have to make sure that on the **Website** and **Store View** is **No**

Comment: I tested and it works.

Comment: Yes, In default it is NO and in website it is set as " Use Default" which is NO and In store view it is set as "Use Website" which is also set as NO.

Comment: What should I do except these steps? is there anything to check?

Comment: you can run `php bin/magento cache:flush`, `php bin/magento cache:clean`, `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` in this order

Comment: @St3phan where I can find Website and Store View Settings on admin-panel

Comment: @AkashAgrawal https://youtu.be/mAlMURRN77M

Comment: @St3phan this video is private, unable to watch it...

Comment: @AkashAgrawal now it is public